# CGRectMake doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on example from "iOS Programming Cookbook", based on iOS 7. I need to create `UITextField` and add it to `ViewController`.

In `ViewController.m` I have:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createField];  
}

- (void) createField {
    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 35.0f, 280.0f, 30.0f)];
    self.textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.textField.placeholder = @"Enter text to share";
    self.textField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
}
```

On screenshot from book `textField` appears in the middle of screen's width under the status bar, but when I run it `textField` appears on the top left corner of screen behind the status bar.

Maybe the problem is, that I run app on iPhone 6 simulator with iOS 8. But I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: does it get positioned differently (or more correctly) if you use the iPhone 5 simulator set to iOS 7?

Comment: Speculation: you're telling it to use an autoresizing mask rather than constraints but not providing any autoresizing information.  I wonder if setting `autoresizingMask` first would help.

Comment: When I use that code in iOS 8 and iphone 6 simulator, it works fine for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `self.textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` is pretty much telling the object that it doesn't really care about the frame but relies more on the constraints that you give it. Setting it to `YES` takes the frame and automatically applies constraints to it to mimic the frame that you give it.

For example it would apply the constraints to have the frame appear at: `CGRectMake(20.0f, 35.0f, 280.0f, 30.0f)`. When setting it to `NO` use `NSLayoutConstraint` and create the constraints programatically.

But in your case just remove the line

```
self.textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

because it is set to `YES` by default.